# The interpretation of Would be in the given sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Q. Who's the guy standing behind you?
>   A. Standing behind me **would be** the guy who helped finish your syllabus two weeks ago.

Here, does **would be** work the same way as **is**?
Standing behind me **is** the guy...?

Answer (score 2):

Your use of

> would be

is equivalent to

> is
>   most probably is
>   is most probably
>
> Q: Who's that on the red carpet with Jonny Depp?
>   A: **That would be** his new girlfriend.
>         *that is his new girlfriend*

Comment: Do we use Would this way to refer to a person only?
Or could would be used instead of is in other cases as well?

Answer (score -1):

You are right, they function the same ("is" would be better, though). In fact, "would be" is commonly used in combination with a possibility, such as

> It would be bad luck if we ran out of gas right now!

I hope this helped you!